# N2CMS - Multilanguage site and SEO friendly URLs

Tags: n2, n2cms

I have a N2 website with 2 languages: English and Serbian.

I want English content to point to `mydomain.com/en`
and Serbian content to point to `mydomain.com/sr`

How can I do that?

Today, URL for English start page is `mydomain.com`
And for Serbian start page: `mydomain.com/Start/Index?page=127`

All pages in my second language don't have SEO friendly URLs.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to organize structure of your site in a following way

```
Root
     Language Intersection
           Start Page EN
           Start Page RS
```

Then, in web.config or config file in App_Data set StartPage to be ID of LanguageIntersection. One of the common causes of non-friendly URLs is that only pages below site start page (as defined in web.config) have friendly URLs. Hence, you must move your start page above each of language start pages.